# Codeigniter file resizing on upload

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been trying to upload and resize an image. The upload seems to be finally be working, but it's not resizing.

In my constructor I am loading the library

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
```

and then in my function I'm calling the the resize and upload

```
    $this->require_auth();      
    $img = $this->input->post('photo1');

    $config['upload_path'] = './HTML/files/';
    $config['file_name'] = 'photo1.jpg';
    $config['file_path'] = './HTML/files/photo1.jpg';
    $config['max-size'] = 2000;
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $config['file_path'];
    $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
    $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
    $config['width']    = 549;
    $config['height']   = 549;
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $config['new_image'] = $config['file_path'];
    $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 
    $this->image_lib->resize();
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);                


    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('photo1')){        
       $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
       var_dump($error);
     }else{
         $this->blog_model->editServiceImg1($config['file_path']); 
         redirect('/blog');
     }
```

I have also tried this

```
    $this->require_auth();      
    $img = $this->input->post('service_photo1');

    $config['upload_path'] = './HTML/files/';
    $config['file_name'] = 'service_photo1.jpg';
    $config['file_path'] = './HTML/files/service_photo1.jpg';
    $config['max-size'] = 2000;
    $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config);                


    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('service_photo1')){        
       $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
       var_dump($error);
     }else{
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $config['file_path'];
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;
        $config['width']    = 549;
        $config['height']   = 549;
        $config['new_image'] = $config['file_path'];
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        $this->image_lib->resize();


         $this->blog_model->editServiceImg1($config['file_path']); 
         redirect('/blog');
     }
```

Is there something I'm missing? I've tried doing the resize after the initial upload as well and that seemed to do nothing as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: u try to resize before upload image?

Comment: @LionKing Unfortunately, it still does not want to work.

Comment: @Xrymz, yes, that is what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: You must upload the image first then, you can resize it, or the image must be exists before resize.

Comment: @LionKing, I have tried that as well. I have put all of the uploading code in the else after the image uploads, but as I stated above it did not work either.

Comment: check chmod of dir, can u write there?

Comment: @LionKing I have echoes it out and it did come back as 1 so it is active and is being used.

Comment: @Xrymz I can write there because the file is uploading, just not resizing.

Comment: Use the following code to see if there is an error: `if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
{
    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
}`

Comment: @LionKing, I have done that. No error comes back it seems to come back fine....just not resizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through this code many times and finally resolved this issue. It seems that when you have

```
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
```

in your code it will create a thumbnail with the resized proportions and if you do not tell it where to go it will hide it in a folder. So the resizing was working, just not on the right image.

To resolve this, I changed the above to.

```
$config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
$config['upload_path'] = './HTML/files/';
$config['file_path'] = './HTML/files/photo1.jpg';
$config['source_image'] = $config['file_path'];
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
$config['width']     = 75;
$config['height']   = 50;

$this->image_lib->clear();
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

If the above code won't work then please check the folder permissions where the images are upload.

You can also give 777 permission to the folder in following manner :-

`sudo chmod -R 777 path`

Solution will surely help you

Comment: I actually figured out what was wrong with it and it was not the permissions. I could write files fine in that folder, they were just not resizing. The issue happened to be that I was setting thumb to be true. So it was resizing and creating another file somewhere else in the app, not in the folder I needed it to be in or the right file. As soon as I set the thumb to false then it worked perfectly.